# How does VBScript store the vbCrLF character within a parsed array of strings?

Tags: arrays, parsing, vbscript

After opening a dialog box to select an input txt file, my script will use the Split function to parse this file into an array of strings delimited by a space. Then I loop through each element of this array and perform one of two actions depending on the situation (using a Switch statement). The intent is to print until I come across a certain string ("Created:") and then do nothing until I come across 4 vbCrLF characters in a row (at this time I will begin printing again until I come across the previously mentioned string). The script is never able to detect these 4 characters in sequence. Even when I attempt to retrieve the value of the array index where I expect a stand-alone vbCrLF to be I find it does not exist at all within the array. If these instances are not stored as elements of the parsed array, how do I locate them?

I can't provide the input txt file, but thx in advance to anyone who can help with this issue.

The code:

(PS ignore the fact that there exists a 'subscript out of range' error for the array loop; this is easily fixed)

```
dim wShell, oExec, objFSO, fIn, fOut, fTest

'Open a dialog box and select the input text file

Set wShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = wShell.Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>""")
txtInFileSelected = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine

'Create object for the input text file
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set fIn = objFSO.OpenTextFile(txtInFileSelected)


'Read in file & close
strData = fIn.ReadAll
fIn.Close
Set fIn = Nothing

'Parse items into array
arrItems = Split(strData)


isItem = 1

'Gather important input data and print in a pleasant format on the output file 
For i = 0 to Ubound(arrItems)




    Select Case isItem

        Case 1
            wscript.echo arrItems(i)
            If arrItems(i+1) <> "Created:" Then
            isItem = 1
            Else 
            isItem = 0
            End If

        Case 0

            If Instr(arrItems(i), vbCr) = 1 And Instr(arrItems(i), vbLF) = 2 And Instr(arrItems(i+1), vbCr) = 1 And Instr(arrItems(i+1), vbLF) = 2 And Instr(arrItems(i+2), vbCr) = 1 And Instr(arrItems(i+2), vbLF) = 2 And Instr(arrItems(i+3), vbCr) = 1 And Instr(arrItems(i+3), vbLF) = 2 Then
            isItem = 1              
            Else 
            isItem = 0

            End If



        End Select



Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting your data like this:

```
BlockTxtArry = Split(strData,vbCRLF & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & vbCRLF)

For Each BlockTxt in BlockTxtArry
    HalfBlock = Split(BlockTxt,"Created:")  
    TxtIwant = HalfBlock(0)  'Section starting with 4x vbcrlf and ending with "Created:"
    TxtIwant = TxtIwant & vbcrlf & "=============" & vbcrlf 
    MsgBox TxtIwant
    AllTxtIwant = AllTxtIwant & vbcrlf & TxtIwant
Next 

MsgBox AllTxtIwant
```